# How can I disable EditTextCell and enable it with EditButton click in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I have a CellTable with EditTextCell, the EditButton is outside of the CellTable. The CellTable will be readonly until I click on the EditButton, the EditTextCell will enable for me to click and edit. Does anybody know how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My custom class:

```
public class ButtonEnableEditTextCell extends EditTextCell {

    private boolean click;

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value, NativeEvent event,
            ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
        if (click) {
            super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
        }
    }

    public void setClick(Boolean click) {
        this.click = click;
    }
}
```

View with table:

```
CellTable<Employee> employeeTable;

@UiField
Button editButton;

ButtonEnableEditTextCell sequenceCell = new ButtonEnableEditTextCell();

@UiHandler("editButton")
public void editButtonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    sequenceCell.setClick(true);
}

private void initTableColumns() {
        Column<Employee, String> sequenceColumn = new Column<Employee, String>(sequenceCell) {
            public String getValue(Employee employee) {
                return employee.getSeqNumber().toString();
            }
        };
        sequenceColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Employee, String>() {
            public void update(int index, Employee employee, String value) {
                employee.setSeqNumber(new Integer(value));
            }
        });
        employeeTable.addColumn(sequenceColumn, "Sequence Number");
}
```

I am able to enable the sequenceColumn with this code.  I wonder if there is better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make your own cell.  You can extend `EditTextCell` and override the `onBrowserEvent` function.  If your button has been clicked and editing is enabled, then call `super.onBrowserEvent`.  If editing is disabled, either do nothing or display an error message.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I knew I have to extend EditTextCell, I was hoping there were other ways to do this without extending EditTextCell. By any chances, do you have working example? Just a fat hope.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need; except wanting to be able to change editability of each cell while running based on the row values. I tested out various combinations of overriding render, isEditing, resetFocus, and edit on EditTextCell (I didn't try the onBrowserEvent solution).

When I only overrode render (to show an HTML value if non-editable); I got errors resetting focus (as [discussed here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Google-Web-Toolkit/fE9TLL0_WAs)). This continued even if I overrode resetFocus. When I only override isEditing, the cell would flash to editing when clicked, and then flash back. What worked perfectly was overriding edit. I triggered based on adding a tag to the value passed in by Column.getValue, you can trigger however you like (ie some setting based on your edit mode), but disabling for a cell turned out to be as simple as:

```
private static class LockableEditTextCell extends EditTextCell {
    @Override
    protected void edit(Context context, Element parent, java.lang.String value) {
      if (!value.startsWith(LOCKED_CELL_VALUE)) {
        super.edit(context, parent, value);
      }
    }
  }
```

Update: this had a bug where if you clicked an editable cell; then a locked cell; it would let you edit. You have to also override onBrowserEvent:

```
@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value,
    NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
  if (!value.startsWith(IncentivesColumnConfigurator.LOCKED_CELL_VALUE)) {
    super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
  }
}
```